# Parallelism in ASP.NET and Process Model Identity in IIS Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, parallel-processing

I use Parallelism in ASP.NET 4, in each Task I have a Connection to Data Base, in most cases I get an exception: `Login failed for user: 'IIS APPPOOL\\MyAppPool'.`

After some search I figured out if I change the Process Model identity in Application pool From `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem` every things would be fine. But Why? Where is the difference between these Identities? I found [Process Model Settings for an Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel)  but I don't understand what related to the Parallelism? Does any one know about this? And is there any other way to use Parallelism and connect to Data Base instead of change Process Model Identity? any suggestion?